# Handling arbitrary number of command line arguments in python

Tags: python

I am trying to have my script be able to take in an arbitrary number of file names as command line arguments. In Unix, it is possible to use the '*' key to represent any character. For example,

```
ls blah*.txt
```

will list every file with blah at the beginning and txt at the end.

I need something like this for my python script.

```
python myscript.py blah*.txt
```

Is this possible? and if it is, how can it be done?

Comment: Windows or Linux?  In windows you have a more complex solution involve 2 lines of code.  In Linux, this is already supported directly and trivially.  See `sys.argv`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats why you have `sys.argv` (and dont forget to `import sys`) It will return all your `blah*.txt` as a list of filenames

Comment: Hmmmm I did not know it could handle it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
  print arg
```

In Unix-land, the shell does the job of glob-expanding the commandline arguments, so you don't need to do it yourself. If you're processing a bunch of files in sequence, you might also look at the [fileinput module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput), which works like Perl's "magic ARGV" handle and the `-n` and `-i` flags. It lets you loop over every line of every file named on the commandline, optionally moving the file to a backup name and opening `stdout` to the original name of the file, which lets you do something simple like:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(inplace = True, backup = '.bak'):
  print fileinput.filelineno() + ": " + line
```

to add the line number to the beginning of every line of every file on the commandline, while saving the originals as `filename.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is also [`fnmatch`](http://docs.python.org/library/fnmatch.html) for when you don't want to have to worry about the path.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys, glob
files = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, (glob.glob(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))
```