# How can I deal with an unknown number of system arguments?

Tags: python

I am writing code that will make a list of system arguments and I need it to work for a different number of arguments.

this is what i have tried with a for loop:

```
import sys
seqs = []
for i in range(len(seqs)):
    seq = sys.argv[i + 1]
    if seq == "":
        break
    seqs.append(seq)
    
print(seqs)
```

and this is what i have tried with a while loop

```
import sys
seqs = []
i = 0
while True:
    seq = sys.argv[i + 1]
    if seq == "":
        break
    seqs.append(seq)
    i += 1
    
print(seqs)
```

Comment: `sys.argv[i + 1]` is going to get an error on the last iteration of the `for` loop, unless there's always an empty argument in the argument list that breaks out of the loop.

Comment: Why not iterate over sys.argv with the for loop?

Comment: Does [Handling arbitrary number of command line arguments in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559477/handling-arbitrary-number-of-command-line-arguments-in-python) answer your question.? Many others searching with `python arbitrary number of command line arguments`.

Comment: Why not simply `args = sys.argv[1:]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information presented in the question, this is the best solution that I have come up with. It's based on the `while` loop code but with a `try` structure added:

```
import sys

seqs = []
i = 0
while True:
    try:
        seq = sys.argv[i + 1]
        if seq == "":
            break
    except:
        break
    seqs.append(seq)
    i += 1

print(seqs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd simplify it to:

```
try:
    blank_pos = sys.argv.index('')
    seqs = sys.argv[1:blank_pos]
except ValueError:
    seqs = []
```

`index()` returns the position of a value in a list, so this finds the first argument whose value is an empty string. It raises `ValueError` if the empthy string can't be found, then I leave `seqs` as an empty list.